# Was there ever a US president who previously served as an independent in Congress?

Tags: united-states, president, congress

I am writing an article about Bernie Sanders and what I think the real reason he lost was. (I think he lost because he was an independent.) But, that is not the point. I want to fact check something that I am writing about. Has there ever been a US president who previously served in Congress as an independent? I don't think there was, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

Thomas Jefferson was a member of the "Congress of the Confederation" (a unicameral body that was a precursor to Congress as defined in the constitution) He is therefore generally considered to have been a "Congressman".  He was (like all the other members of Congress) an independent, as the first party system had not yet developed.  (He would later, of course, become the leader of the Democratic-Republican Party)

James Madison, the other founder of the Democratic-Republican party was a Representative in the first Congress following the ratification of the Constitution. Again, he stood as an "independent", as no Party system then existed (although a division between "federalists" and "anti-federalists" already existed).

For many of the Early Senators, party affiliation is somewhat unclear.  Senators were not elected and owed their positions thanks to preferment in the State Legislature.  There were periods such as during the chaos of the 1820s and 1830s, in which "party" was almost irrelevant.  The important fact was which faction or clique within the Democratic-Republicans one belonged to (particularly if you were a Jacksonite or anti-Jacksonite) There were probably Senators who were clearly identified as Jacksonite, who were not formally a member of any party.

Mention might be made of Millard Fillmore, who stood for Congress not as an Independent, but as an "Anti-Mason" (a single issue party whose main policy, besides opposing Freemasonry was "Anti-Jackson")  This was one of the groups that would develop into the Whigs and later (following mergers and splits) develop into the Republican party of Abraham Lincoln.)  However the Presidency of Taylor and Fillmore (Fillmore was VP, but Taylor died shortly after taking office) was the closest that the US has had to an "Independent" president.  Taylor himself was a military hero of vague Whiggish political views.

Comment: That seems like somewhat of a special case, though, given that political parties hadn't really been created yet in this time in history. But still worth mentioning, so I still gave you a +1.

Comment: I've added another, slightly nearer the present.  Millard Fillmore.  Not the greatest name in Presidential history...